# Play/Pause HTML5 video using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video, playback

I would like to play/pause video using jquery.

Here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
    // plugin definition
    $.fn.htmlvideo = function (options) {
        // build main options before element iteration
        var defaults = {
            theme: 'normal',
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        // iterate and reformat each matched element
        return this.each(function () {
            var $htmlvideo = $(this);

            addvideo();
            addcontrols();


            function addvideo() {
                var addvideo = $('<video width="1000"><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis""><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2""></video>');
                $(addvideo).appendTo('#video');
            }

            function addcontrols() {
                var controls = $('<div id="controls" class="controls"><button id="playbtn" class="playbtn"></button></div>');
                $(controls).appendTo('#controlspane');
            }

            $('.playbtn').click(function () {
               //Here I need to make the video play
            });


        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add ann id to the video control

```
function addvideo() {
            var addvideo = $('<video controls="controls" width="480" height="208" id="videoo"><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis""><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2""></video>');
             $(addvideo).appendTo('body');


        }
```

use delegate as the button you are adding is dynamic

```
$(document).delegate('.playbtn',"click",function () {    
        $('#videoo')[0].play();        
});
```

`$("#videoo")[0]` will return you the DOM element not the jQuery object as the `play` method is not the jquery method its the DOM method

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSTPv/9/)

Comment: @3nigma-Thanks again for sorting me the problem.

Comment: glad that helped, from the previous question i noticed that you are using the multiple ids in the anchor and in the video control, that is wrong the ids should be unique...

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$('video').trigger('play');
$('video').trigger('pause');
```

For more: http://wonderdesigners.com/?p=219